# Linq OrderBy calculated property

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I use expression builder to sort and filter table data. However, the query doesn't execute when there's a calculation in the property.

I read similar post here but couldn't find an answer!

e.g. if I try to sort the query below by "Due", it fails with the error below.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(i => i.OrganisationId == __organisationId_0)
> .OrderBy(i => (Nullable)(DateTime.Now - i.PaymentDueDate).TotalDays)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

How do I cope this situation or am I doing anything wrong here?
thanks, much appreciated!

Method:

```
public async Task<PaginatedList<GetInvoiceListDto>> Handle(GetInvoiceListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var organisationId = _tenantService.GetOrganisationId();
        return await _context.Invoices
            .Include(i => i.InvoiceSaleItems)
            .Where(w => w.OrganisationId == organisationId)
            .Select(y => new GetInvoiceListDto
            {
                Status = y.PaymentDueDate < DateTime.Now ? "Overdue" : "Sent",
                Due = (DateTime.Now - y.PaymentDueDate).TotalDays,
                InvoiceDate = y.InvoiceDate,
                InvoiceNumber = y.InvoiceNumber,
                CustomerName = y.Customer.CustomerName,
                AmountDue = y.InvoiceSaleItems.Sum(yx => yx.Amount) + y.InvoiceSaleItems.SelectMany(ss => ss.InvoiceSaleItemTaxes).Sum(sg => sg.Amount),
            }).PaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize, request.SortColumn, request.SortOrder, request.q);

    }
```

Extension:

```
public static Task<PaginatedList<TDestination>> PaginatedListAsync<TDestination>(this IQueryable<TDestination> queryable, int pageNumber, int pageSize, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, string filter)
        => PaginatedList<TDestination>.CreateAsync(queryable, pageNumber, pageSize, sortColumn, sortOrder, filter);


public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, string filter)
    {
        var query = source;
        // query = query.Filter<T>(filter); // commented for simplicity.
        query = query.OrderBy<T>(sortColumn, sortOrder);
        var count = query.Count(); // <= The error is thrown at this line.
        var items = await Task.FromResult (query.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());

        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }

public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction)
    {
        var methodNameFirst = string.Format("OrderBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
        var methodNameContinue = string.Format("ThenBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");
        Expression result = query.Expression;
        var methodName = methodNameFirst;
        foreach (var fields in sortColumn.Split(','))
        {
            Expression memberAccess = null;
            foreach (var property in fields.Split('.'))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.Trim()) == false)
                {
                    var newProp = "";
                    if (property.IndexOf(" asc") == -1)
                    {
                        newProp = property.Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newProp = property.Substring(0, property.IndexOf(" asc")).Trim();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property(memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), newProp);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            LambdaExpression orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);
            result = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                methodName,
                new[] { query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type },
                result,
                Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));
            methodName = methodNameContinue;
        }
        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
    }
```

Comment: C# expressions can represent a superset of operations compare to those that can be executed. You're trying to do something that can't be executed on the database, but can be in memory. Your choices, as clearly articulated in the error message, are to rewrite your query to not use your custom calculation or to bring the results into memory, before the calculation, and do the calculation with plain C# code.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks! how do I execute the query in the memory and still get use of pagination? could you please give me an example?

Comment: Or how do I re-write the query so that it can be executed at the database level?

Comment: You have to bring all of the data into memory, do the calculation, and then paginate. Now, that might be too memory intensive, so you might need to bring in the minimal data to determine which ids are in which page and then go back to the db for the actual data.

Comment: I can't tell you how to re-write your query. You just have to remove the offending code and then figure out what calculations can work on the DB. It's not necessarily an easy thing to do.

Comment: It would have been so much easier if I had to bring whole 100k records into the memory. that's out of my equation though. I will see if I can re-write the query in a way it can be executed at the Db level. a simple example would have been still handy here. cheers!

Comment: I can't think of a simple example of converting a custom calculation to something that can run on the DB. I generally prefer to bring things in to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `(DateTime.Now - y.PaymentDueDate).TotalDays` try to replace with something that EF Core can translate to the SQL:

```cs
return await _context.Invoices
    .Where(w => w.OrganisationId == organisationId)
    .Select(y => new GetInvoiceListDto
    {
        Status = y.PaymentDueDate < DateTime.Now ? "Overdue" : "Sent",
        Due = EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(DateTime.Now, y.PaymentDueDate),
        InvoiceDate = y.InvoiceDate,
        InvoiceNumber = y.InvoiceNumber,
        CustomerName = y.Customer.CustomerName,
        AmountDue = y.InvoiceSaleItems.Sum(yx => yx.Amount) + y.InvoiceSaleItems.SelectMany(ss => ss.InvoiceSaleItemTaxes).Sum(sg => sg.Amount),
    }).PaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize, request.SortColumn, request.SortOrder, request.q);
```

Note, that I have removed `Include` which is not needed if you have `Select`.